# Help me solve this Yamato/Ultimate wooden block puzzle

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, burr-puzzle

I was recently at grandma's. Found this wooden puzzle her friend had made that I took apart as I thought it would be easy to put it back together. Turns out it was not.

I have identified is as The Yamato Block at [Rob's Puzzle page](http://www.robspuzzlepage.com/interlocking.htm). I am able to find [solutions](https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/%7Estorer/JimPuzzles/BURR/6PieceLev1Yamato/YamatoSolution.jpg) googling it, but they are hand drawn and I am having trouble following it.

Anyone who can point me to a better instruction?

Here are my pieces lined up as in the solution:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just wanting the diagrams to be clearer? TinkerCad is pretty easy to learn and free. I made these if you want to play with them: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/kOCVDD6zTu9-yamoto-pieces

[image: Yamoto Pieces]

Then following the instructions (which your link starts at step 2):

Step 2 (front view):

[image: Step 2]

Step 3 (left side view):

[image: Step 3]

Step 4 (right side view):

[image: Step 4]

Step 5 (right side view):

[image: Step 5]

And then just put the last piece in.